# Nested JSON in Kendo ui not loading

Tags: javascript, json, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am new to kendo ui development i want to show this response in kendo ui grid. I studied in kendo api document i mentioned schema. i loaded the values but the problem is
In my response "options" having one json object and "objects " having array of json objects.In my grid "objects" value are loaded as [object object].
How to over come this problem.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the schema as:

```
schema  : {
    data    : "objects",
    total : "options.totalCount"
}
```

Which means that you are going receive a JSON structure *but* [`data`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.data) (for the grid) is actually in a field of this JSON called `objects`.

For [`total`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.total) is similar, the pre-computed `total` comes from the server in `options.totalCount`.

If you want to see it running in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/hza7j/

Comment: Onabai@: In the above response i have to show all attributes in single column of my grid.

Comment: I have added an image. Like that i have to show my attributes values in grid

Comment: @DIVAKARSRINIVASAN, this is actually a different question. You should consider posting different question as new in order to make it as visible as possible. If you reply to me, it's likely that I'm the only one seeing it. Did I answer your original question, consider accepting it, so others would know about it.